# Weighting data based on the errors

Tags: poisson-distribution, curve-fitting, measurement-error, weights

I have some data (counts) with a Poisson error associated with them and I want to fit the data. I am trying to weight the data inversely proportional to the errors, such that the data points with high errors are less important for the fit. However, using the the error on its own, doesn't seem right.

For example, if I have a point with a value $100 \pm 10$ and another one with the value $10000 \pm 100$, the first one has a smaller error, but the second one should be (I think) more important for the fit, as the relative error is much smaller.

So should I weight each data point by the inverse of its percentage error, i.e., the first point would have a weight of $10$, while the other a weight of $100$? Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If the values are independent Poisson and you seek a best estimate of the common mean, just sum and divide by the total exposure (or by the number of terms if the exposures are the same, in which case you have a mean per observation rather than per unit of expsosure).

This will correspond to both maximum likelihood estimation of the Poisson parameter, and to weighting in the sample average in proportion to the inverse of the estimated variance. Note that in the case of known variances, [inverse-variance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) is optimal for a weighted mean.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. So I have some data points to which I want to fit a Voigt profile + background. For each data point I have the energy, the counts and the error (square root of the number of counts). The background counts are around 100 (so error of 10) and the peak of the signal around 10,000 (so error of 100). If I would weight inversely proportional to the error, the background would be 10 times more important for the fit than the signal, which I definitely don't want. Am I miss understanding this?

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of new information that's not in the question I answered. There's no easy way to alter my response from answering the (seemingly) simple question you posted to this considerably more complex situation. Please post a new question.

Comment: The only new information is the Voigt profile, but that is not that important for my question (it can be a Gaussian or something else). The main issues (which is explained in the original question), is how to fit a function (Voigt or not) to some data, in which the points are counts, and the error associated to each point is square root of the number of counts (i.e. Poisson error).

Comment: That's not the only thing not clear in the original; more important than the specific profile is the fact that you are actually fitting an interval-censored distributional model ... none of which was clear in the post. An entirely different kind of answer is required for that.

Comment: What do you mean by interval-censored distributional model?

Comment: That's why it takes a new question.... you have observations assumed to be from some distribution, but the observations are [interval censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)#Types).

Comment: Sorry I am still confused (I want to make sure I understand what was wrong, so I can post the new question in the right form). I see that "interval censored" means that the data is between 2 values (so I assumed like in a bin?). Isn't this how data is always presented? Like you can't have infinite resolution in a counts measurement, so you need some bins. Am I missing something (I am not sure what is the confusion in my first post). Thank you!

Comment: "isn't this how data is always presented?"  ... well, yes and no. If I am asking 1000 people their total annual income as stated on their tax return, I mightn't see even a single duplicate value. If bins are wide enough that you really need to start counting the values (i.e. there's regularly a substantial number of multiple values in a bin, as if I asked them their income to the nearest thousand dollars, say), then the binning may matter; often you couldn't really treat it as continuous then. If I were to ask about incomes to the nearest 10 thousand or some larger interval, it matters more.

Comment: I see what you mean, but still, you need to use some bins, no matter how sparse the data is (even if you have one count per bin) and I mean in practice not in theory. If you don't use bins, then you should associate to each real number a count (so basically you need infinite digits) and you can never reach 10,000 counts (as in my case), in one bin, if that bin is infinitely narrow i.e. just a real number, unless you have infinite statistics. Also the measurement of the x axis (in general) has some errors, so basically in practice you are forced to have bins by your resolution Isn't this right?